# UITableView Signal SIGBRT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My View controller has just a `UITableView`:

[image: The View Controller]

and When I tries to move to this tab, there comes a Signal SIGBRT error.
and this is my code.

```
//
//  FriendTableViewController.swift
//  Tiat
//
//  Created by 이종승 on 2016. 9. 23..
//  Copyright © 2016년 JW. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class FriendTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var users = [User]()
    let cellId = "friendsCell"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchUser()

    }
    @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!

    func fetchUser () {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()
                user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
                user.gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String
                user.birthday = dictionary["birthday"] as? String
                user.point = dictionary["point"] as? Int

                print(user.name, user.gender, user.birthday, user.point)
                self.users.append(user)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        return cell
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

//Error Log//

```
2016-09-23 23:49:33.092 Tiat[14923:1376968] *** Terminating app due to      uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "8rJ-Kc-sve-view-QS5-Rx-YEW" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f94734b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f3a821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b0265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011018b7d2 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 532
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ff0bc4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ff4c44f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 55
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ff4cd37 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 471
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010ff4ceae -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 133
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ff4e0b9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ff4f19b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001101461b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010fe2f344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114ba4cdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b987a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b9861e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b2662c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b53713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010fd64067 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000110573b30 __handleEventQueue + 5672
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8ec311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8d159c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8d0a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8d0494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112696a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010fd6af34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  Tiat                                0x000000010cdcc6cf main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111f8e68d start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

*Edited*

and There is one more very strange thing.

I tried running my code with all of my code deleted, and there comes same error as before!

Comment: Add the error message...

Answer (score 1):

Guessing, You have not created a Prototype cell.

Add a cell to this tableview and give it the Identifier name you have assigned to the `cellId`.

Comment: And the reuse identifier should be in quotes.

Comment: It shouldn't be so, OP has declared a variable with `cellId` name.